# Unable to remove Read-Only attribute from folder

Tags: vmware-esxi, read-only

I have a Windows Server 2012R2VM File Server on an ESXi host (lab environment, domain joined). Everything seems to work just fine on the the environment. I am testing a new software which utilises SQL 2014 Express (installed on this server) and the developers recommendation is to move the databases to a separate drive and they provide all the instructions on how to do this on SQL which is great.

I added an extra disk on the VM, partitioned the disk in 2 partitions (1 as NTFS with 4096K allocation block and 2 as ReFS with 64K allocation block, as per the developers recommendation). I followed their instructions and moved the databases successfully.

But here is the problem - the databases are showing as read only in SQL and the software cannot read/write to them. After some searching I saw that the root folders (within with the database files reside) on the 2 partitions were set to Read-Only, which seems to be causing the issue.

I tried to use the "attrib -R -S e:\foldername" to remove the read-only attribute, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Pantelis

Comment: Apparently, the default DATA folder for the SQL Server on C: is also Read-Only. If I create a new Database with the .mdf file on the E: partition (NTFS) and the .ldf file on the F: partition (ReFS), the database works just fine. If I move the files in the default location for SQL Server, it works fine. If I move it back to the orignal location (partitions E and F) it shows up as Read-Only again and I am unable to take any actions on it.

Comment: The only thing the read-only flag does for a directory is to prevent the directory from being removed.  It doesn't prevent creating or modifying files the directory contains.  That is more likely to be another symptom than the cause of the problem.  Check that the disk itself isn't read-only, if you are using `diskpart` you can do this with the `detail disk` command.